# Redefining Friend Function of Base Class in Derived Class

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend, derived-class

I want to redefine the `operator*` function that is originally defined as a friend in the `Vector` class, in a derived class, `BigNum`.  Specifically I want to call the `Vector` version of `operator*` and then do some other things to the result of that operation in `BigNum`'s operator*.  Here's a snippet of the structure (thanks again to @lemmes for helping with this):

```
template<typename T>
class Vector
{
private:
  std::vector<T> base;

public:                                                                                                                 
  Vector();                                                                                                                        
  Vector(const std::vector<T> vec);                                                                                                
  Vector(const Vector& vec);

  template<typename T1, typename T2>
  friend auto operator*(const Vector<T1>& lhs, const Vector<T2>& rhs) -> Vector<decltype(std::declval<T1>() * std::declval<T2>())>;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator*(const Vector<T1>& lhs, const Vector<T2>& rhs) -> Vector<decltype(std::declval<T1>() * std::declval<T2>())>
{
  typedef decltype(std::declval<T1>() * std::declval<T2>()) T3;
  assert(lhs.base.size() == rhs.base.size());
  Vector<T3> result;
  result.base.reserve(lhs.base.size());
  std::transform(lhs.base.begin(), lhs.base.end(), rhs.base.begin(), std::back_inserter(result.base),
                 [](const T1& e1, const T2& e2) { return e1 * e2; });
  return result;
}

class BigNum : public Vector<int>
{
 public:
  BigNum();
  BigNum(const std::vector<int> init);
  ~BigNum();

  BigNum operator*(const BigNum& rhs);
};
#endif

BigNum BigNum::operator*(const BigNum& rhs)
{

  // How can I call Vector's operator* (a friend of the Vector class)                                                                            
  // and then do other stuff in here?                                                                                                            
}

#include "BigNum.h"

int main()
{

  int arr1[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  int arr2[] = {10,20,30,40,50};
  std::vector<int> vec1 (arr1, arr1 + sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]));
  std::vector<int> vec2 (arr2, arr2 + sizeof(arr2) / sizeof(arr2[0]));

  BigNum bn1(vec1), bn2(vec2);

  bn1 * bn2;  // want to call BigNum's operator* here

  return 0;
}
```

I obviously can't do something like `Vector::operator*` since it's a friend.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can write `static_cast<Vector<int>&>(bn1) * static_cast<Vector<int>&>(bn2)` to have the vector's overloaded operator called.

Comment: Cool, I added that to the definition of `operator+` in `BigNum`, but why can't I assign the result to a `BigNum` object?  I.e I want to return a BigNum object, so I'd like to do `BigNum result =static_cast<Vector<int>&>(bn1) * static_cast<Vector<int>&>(bn2)

Comment: @David: Who said you can't? Write an appropriate constructor. But it sounds like madness.

Comment: I wrote a copy constructor, but I still get the error "conversion from 'Vector<int>' to non-scalar type 'BigNum' requested